# macOS command Unable to access a.jar

Tags: macos, sh

I have a jar called `a.jar`. When I execute it with `java -jar a.jar` everything works correctly. But when I create this `.command` file:

```
#!/bin/bash
java -jar a.jar
```

execute `chmod u+x launch.command` and run it by double clicking, the terminal window displays

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile a.jar
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you run a `.command` file, it executes in your `~` (user) directory, that is why it is not able to find your `a.jar` file. You need to give the path of your `a.jar` to execute it from your `.command` file.

```
#!/bin/bash
java -jar path-to-file/a.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

If running this from Intelli J on a Mac, always add the path-to-file which in my case was the target directory. Navigating **"into"** the target directory and running `java -jar test.jar` was **the** problem for me. The correct way is;

```
java -jar target/test.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

This can happen when your are connected via SSH and the machine user is not logged in or its locked. MAC OS does not allow to run java -jar commands and returns Error: Unable to access jarfile a.jar. In order to solve it, just do the user login first.